# Protractor- Retrieve value of global array in a function

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to push array content in a global defined empty array & then retrieve its contents inside another function.

Below is the code which i tried:

```
describe('My Test', function() {
var arrayf3=[];
 var indexf3='not found';
    it('Test starts', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/angular/');
    var elm = element(by.id('leftmenuinner')).all(By.css('[target="_top"]'));
    elm.count().then(function(count) {
        Methods.pushToArray(0, count, elm);
    })
    var texttocheck='Data Binding';
    Methods.getIndex(0, arrayf3.length, arrayf3, texttocheck);
    console.log('Text content of global array is ' + arrayf3);
    console.log('index of the array number having texttofind is ' + indexf3);
    })
    var Methods = {
    getIndex :function (i, max, array, texttocheck) {
        if (i < max) {
        console.log('text[' + i + '].indexOf = ' + array[i].indexOf(texttocheck))
        if (array[i].indexOf(texttocheck) > 0) {
            indexf3 = i;
        } else {
            Methods.getIndex(i + 1, max, array, texttocheck);
        }
        }
    },

    pushToArray :function (i, max, elm) {
        if (i < max) {
        elm.get(i).getText().then(function(tmpText) {
            console.log("The array "+tmpText);
            arrayf3.push(tmpText);     
        })
        Methods.pushToArray(i + 1, max, elm);
        }

    },

    }
});
```

Problem is i am getting null values for below placeholder values:

Text content of global array is

index of the array number having texttofind is

I want the array value copied in this global empty array to be used & displayed in the same it block function 'Test starts'

Answer (score 1):

Protractor's `element.all` inherently knows how to `getText()` on each of the elements and return the values as an array.

```
    it('Test starts', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/angular/');

        var getIndexOfElementByPartialText = function(inputText) {
            return element(by.id('leftmenuinner')).all(by.css('[target="_top"]')).getText().then(function(values) {
                var indexNumber;
                values.forEach(function(value, index) {
                    if (new RegExp(inputText).test(value)) {
                        if (indexNumber === undefined) {
                            indexNumber = index;
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('multiple elements match the input text');
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (indexNumber === undefined) {
                    throw new Error('no elements match the input text');
                } else {
                    return indexNumber;
                }
            });
        });

        expect(getIndexOfElementByPartialText('thing1').toBe(1);
        expect(getIndexOfElementByPartialText('thing2').toBe(2);
    });
```

Edited the answer to provide it in terms of a re-usable function.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. Please read the question & the code again to understand what it is intended to do & what do i actually want from it. The answer that you have posted just prints the array values, i want the array contents to be pushed in a blank array(globally defined) and then find the index number of the partial text using the indexOf method.